# Javascript: Modifying documentFragment and inserting it multiple times

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes, clone

I have a double question.

I have some markup in a HTML-template tag. That I query, and output multiple time to the page, with small moderation.

I've made an example to show what's going on: https://jsbin.com/ruwuvanetu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
<body>
  
  <template>
    <div class="post">
      <h2 class="headline">Headline</h2>
      <p>Paragraph text</p>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    
  </div>
  
</body>
```

and my JS like so

```
const template = document.querySelector('template');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');


for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   
  const headline = template.content.querySelector('.headline');
  
  console.log(template);
  
  if(i === 1) {
    headline.remove();
  }
  console.log(template);
  
  wrapper.innerHTML += template.innerHTML;

}
```

**Question 1**

How come the changes made to one template, affects the upcoming ones?
I figured I could solve it, by cloning the template before making the changes, but I didn't manage to find any documentation on that, and I'm curious to hear, if this is expected behaviour?

**Question 2**

Now that I solved question 1 with clone, I'm still puzzled as to how the references are working.
Here is an evolution of Q1 https://jsbin.com/lobogahoce/1/edit?html,js,console,output where the modifications dosen't affect the next ones, but I can't understand why the same template is outputtet by the two console.log(temp) statement before and after the if block?

I would expect the first log to output what it does, but I would expect the second one, in the second loop iteration to output the template without the headline. But they seem the same.

Hope it makes sense.
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't clone the node, then `temp` is a reference to the same node, so why wouldn't changes to the node affect it?

Comment: My thought was, that since the modified innerHTML had been inserted to the DOM, it was no longer relevant. But is the if statement removing the "headline" from the general template tag?

Comment: Yes, the remove is removing it from the template.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: Would that still be the case, if the whole for loop was wrapped in a function, where the template was passed as an argument?

Comment: Yes, because regardless of what variable or method or reference you use, they would all be affecting the same single DOM

Comment: Thanks @Taplar that explains question 1

Comment: The console log question is a duplicate.  The browser when you log something will show you its last value, not what it was at the time that it is logged, if the thing being logged is mutable.  DOM Elements are mutable.  Browsers do this to try to be helpful, but it ends up confusing new developers who are not aware of this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Taplar. I expected the logs to happen in the order they appeared in the code, and I therefor used them to track changes. But clearly that don't work then.

Comment: They do happen in the expected order.  They just are not static.